# how to create custom gridlayout with drag and drop views?

Tags: android, grid

I want to create a custom GridLayout with custom items/view to drag an drop inside the GridLayout.Please help me regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/askerov/DynamicGrid) and [This](https://code.google.com/p/android-gridview-drag-and-drop/)

Answer (score 0):

Refer this Custom Grid View 
https://github.com/thquinn/DraggableGridView
It has drag-and-dropproperties as per your requirement.

Comment: thanks @Nitesh but i need GridLayout. Look i want to create a view like chess board. Where i can drag my objects at specific (XY) coordinates. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Using Canvas would be an option for you.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial will help you to create custom grid layout
http://androidexample.com/Custom_Grid_Layout_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=76&aaid=100

this tutorial will help you to create drag and drop gestures concept
https://capdroid.wordpress.com/2012/07/18/android-drag-and-drop_tutorial/